# Include JavaScript code in HTML using tex4ht

Tags: miktex, tex4ht, html, javascript

I have trouble including JavaScript code in the HTML header generated by tex4ht.

The script I want to include is:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  var _gaq = _gaq || [];
  var pluginUrl = 
   '//www.google-analytics.com/plugins/ga/inpage_linkid.js';
  _gaq.push(['_require', 'inpage_linkid', pluginUrl]);
  _gaq.push(['_setAccount', 'UA-45193039-1']);
  _gaq.push(['_trackPageview']);
  (function() {
    var ga = document.createElement('script'); ga.type = 'text/javascript'; ga.async = true;
    ga.src = ('https:' == document.location.protocol ? 'https://ssl' : 'http://www') + '.google-analytics.com/ga.js';
    var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0]; s.parentNode.insertBefore(ga, s);
  })();
</script>
```

Can anybody tell me how to do this. The documentation on the

```
\JavaScript .....\EndJavaScript
```

command in the Tex4ht online manual (mn) is not very helpful and gives loads of incomprehensible error messages.

Herman Adèr

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx) Can you tell us, what you have tried out inclusive the error messages you've got?

Comment: I used Miktex to translate my LaTeX code including the TeX4ht package. In the .cfg file I first tried to use \ScriptEnv to make a JavaScript environment. But it fails to generate the script above as a verbatim insertion. Surrounding with \JavaScript...\EndJavaScript

Comment: does not work either.

Answer (score 2):

The manual isn't very helpful in this case, it is even misleading, because `\JavaScript` command isn't defined by default, only when `javascript` option is used it is defined. But it is quite easy to define your own version:

```
\Preamble{xhtml}
\begin{document}
  \ScriptCommand{\JavaScript}{\HCode{\Hnewline<script type="text/javascript">\Hnewline}}{\HCode{\Hnewline</script>\Hnewline}}
\JavaScript
var _gaq = _gaq || [];
var pluginUrl = 
  '//www.google-analytics.com/plugins/ga/inpage_linkid.js';
_gaq.push(['_require', 'inpage_linkid', pluginUrl]);
_gaq.push(['_setAccount', 'UA-45193039-1']);
_gaq.push(['_trackPageview']);
(function() {
 var ga = document.createElement('script'); ga.type = 'text/javascript'; ga.async = true;
 ga.src = ('https:' == document.location.protocol ? 'https://ssl' : 'http://www') + '.google-analytics.com/ga.js';
 var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0]; s.parentNode.insertBefore(ga, s);
 })();
\EndJavaScript
\EndPreamble
```

In this configuration file, `\JavaScript` command is defined first:

```
\ScriptCommand{\JavaScript}{\HCode{\Hnewline<script type="text/javascript">\Hnewline}}{\HCode{\Hnewline</script>\Hnewline}}
```

The `\Hnewline` commands are used to insert line breaks. The JavaScript code is then inserted without `<script ...>` tags, because `\JavaScript` command will take care of this.

One important thing is to place the JavaScript after `\begin{document}` in the configuration file, this ensures that it is inserted in the `HTML` header:

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?> 
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" 
  "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">  
<!--http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd-->  
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"  
> 
<head>  
<script type="text/javascript"> 
var _gaq = _gaq || [];
var pluginUrl =
  '//www.google-analytics.com/plugins/ga/inpage_linkid.js';
_gaq.push(['_require', 'inpage_linkid', pluginUrl]);
_gaq.push(['_setAccount', 'UA-45193039-1']);
_gaq.push(['_trackPageview']);
(function() {
 var ga = document.createElement('script'); ga.type = 'text/javascript'; ga.async = true;
 ga.src = ('https:' == document.location.protocol ? 'https://ssl' : 'http://www') + '.google-analytics.com/ga.js';
 var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0]; s.parentNode.insertBefore(ga, s);
 })();

</script> 
<title>mytitle</title> 
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" /> 
<meta name="generator" content="TeX4ht (http://www.tug.org/tex4ht/)" /> 
<meta name="originator" content="TeX4ht (http://www.tug.org/tex4ht/)" /> 
<!-- charset=utf-8,html,xhtml --> 
<meta name="src" content="sample.tex" /> 
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="sample.css" /> 
</head><body 
>
```

Comment: Thank you very much. I found the same solution. I will also try the javascript option you suggest.

Comment: In the original question I made another mistake somewhere else in the config file which accounted for the error messages. Thanks again. Problem solved.

Comment: Is there a way to do this so that the JavaScript appears after the MathJax JavaScript?

Comment: @Rushi I would just link to external JS in `\Configure{@/BODY}' or something similar.

Comment: @michal.h21 thanks, I will try. I am trying to do a sidebar [similar to this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/563101/110602), and I am using [this configuration](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/522893/110602) to insert macros. The problem is that the macros, when processed by MathJax, result in a bunch of empty and hidden `mjx-container` html tags that are direct children of `<body>`. Those throw off the grid layout you use in [the documentation](https://www.kodymirus.cz/tex4ht-doc/texfourhtOptions.html). I am now trying a JavaScript to get rid of those, but it needs to load after MathJax.

Comment: @Rushi ah, you can also get rid of the unwanted HTML tags using make4ht DOM filters. I think it would be better than using JS. Best would be to modify the configuration to not even output them. It probably deserves new question with a full MWE.

Comment: @michal.h21 thanks for the suggestion! I do not think the problem is with `tex4ht`, though. The unwanted HTML tags are not there in the `tex4ht` HTML output. The unwanted tags appear where all the `\newcommand` macros are, after the HTML is processed by MathJaX. That is why I tried a post-MathJaX JS solution. I suppose one option would be to move the `\newcommand` macros inside the `<main>` tag in the configuration. I will try that next!

Comment: @Rushi maybe try to put these newcommands into a `<div>`  and hide it using CSS (like `display:none`)

Comment: @michal.h21 that worked. The JS solution to add styles directly to the `mjx-container` tags was messing with equation referencing for some reason, but putting the macros in a hidden `div` solves everything. Thanks!

Comment: @Rushi that's good to hear! the easiest solutions are usually the best :)