# How to configure tex4ht to accept macros in TeX path?

Tags: macros, tex4ht, htlatex, mathjax, make4ht

I am using the configuration suggested in [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/522893/110602) to import a file `Macros.tex` containing a bunch of `\newcommand` macros to be processed using MathJax. It works as long as the main LaTeX file and `Macros.tex` are in the same folder. If `Macros.tex` is somewhere else on the tex path, `pdflatex` finds it, but `tex4ht` cannot.

The `.sty` and the `.cfg` file can be anywhere on the TeX path, but the two `.tex` files have to be in the same folder, otherwise the macros do not get included in the HTML file. Is there a way to use a global macros file in this setup?

`test.tex`

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{MyMacros}
\begin{document}
    $ \frac{\diff x}{\diff y} $
\end{document}
```

`Macros.tex`

```
\newcommand\diff{\mathop{}\!\mathrm{d}}
```

`MyMacros.sty`

```
\ProvidesPackage{MyMacros}
    \input{Macros.tex}
\endinput
```

`myconfig.cfg`

```
\Preamble{xhtml,mathjax}
\Configure{@BODY}{\IgnorePar
\HCode{\detokenize{\(}}
\special{t4ht*<Macros.tex}
\HCode{\detokenize{\)}}
\par
}
\begin{document}
\EndPreamble
```

Comment: the cfg file will be found via the input path but `\special{t4ht*<mymacros.tex}` is I suspect not. What happens if you put the full path there `\special{t4ht*</some/path.to/mymacros.tex}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `Macros.tex` file should be included verbatim by the `tex4ht` command. It doesn't support the KPSE library for searching of files (it supports it for some purposes, but obviously not for files requested using `\special{t4ht*<`).

Fortunately, we can use the KPSE library included in LuaTeX to find your file:

```
\Preamble{xhtml,mathjax}
\Configure{@BODY}{\IgnorePar
\HCode{\detokenize{\(}}
\special{t4ht*<\directlua{tex.print(kpse.find_file("Macros.tex"))}}
\HCode{\detokenize{\)}}
\par
}
\begin{document}
\EndPreamble
```

The important line is this:

```
\special{t4ht*<\directlua{tex.print(kpse.find_file("Macros.tex"))}}
```

`kpse.find_file` returns full path to a file found in TeX path, `tex.print` prints it to the input, so the `\special` command gets the correct path.

This is the resulting HTML file:

```xml
<body>
\( \newcommand\diff{\mathop{}\!\mathrm{d}} \)
<!-- l. 4 --><p class='indent'>   \( \frac {\diff x}{\diff y} \) </p> 
</body>
```

[image]