# make4ht: can it generate framed html output?

Tags: html, make4ht

I am using `make4ht` to generate HTML output for an article that I am writing and posting it online. So far, so good. I would like to know if it would be possible to generate framed HTML output so that you always have the menu on the left pane, content on the right pane and so on.

I was thinking that I could set up a framed index.html page that pulls the main html generated from `make4ht` (which is basically the menu) on the left and then have some initial content page on the right pane. Can modify the main page generated from `make4ht` (after the fact) to have `"_target"` set up to the other frame on all the links (if I remember correctly how to do this thing in html)... but it would be so much nicer to have `make4ht` do it *automagically* for me.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can try the [`frames`](https://www.kodymirus.cz/tex4ht-doc/texfourhtOptions.html#x7-300006) option if really want to use frames. Like in this example:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{kantlipsum}
\begin{document}
\chapter{Hello}
\kant[1-3]
\chapter{World}
\section{Section}
\kant[4-5]
\section{Another Section}
\kant[6-7]
\end{document}
```

Compile the file using

```
make4ht filename.tex "3,frames"
```

And it produces the following HTML page:

[image]

Another option is to use method that I use for the [work in progress Tex4ht documentaton](https://www.kodymirus.cz/tex4ht-doc/texfourhtOptions.html#x7-300006). See the [Github repo](https://github.com/michal-h21/tex4ht-doc) for configurations I used.

In contrast to frames, TOC is inserted on each page, but it contains links only to top level sectioning levels. Only the current chapter sections are shown.

In particular, HTML code that inserts TOC is configured in [config.cfg](https://github.com/michal-h21/tex4ht-doc/blob/master/config.cfg):

```
% Mini TOC
\Configure{crosslinks+}{%
  \bgroup
  % container for the page toc
  \Configure{tableofcontents}{\IgnorePar\EndP\HCode{<nav class="TOC">}\IgnorePar}
  {\HCode{\Hnewline}}{\IgnorePar\HCode{</nav>\Hnewline}\ShowPar}{}{}%
  \TableOfContents[chapter,section,subsection]% Print table of contents before crosslinks
  \egroup
  \ifvmode\IgnorePar\fi\EndP%
  \HCode{<main class="main-content">\Hnewline<nav class="crosslinks-top">} }
  {\HCode{</nav>\Hnewline}}
{\ifvmode\IgnorePar\fi\EndP%
  \HCode{<nav class="crosslinks-bottom">}}{\HCode{</nav>}}{}{}
```

Sectioning commands that are included in TOC are selected using the `\TableOfContents` command. Appearance of TOC is styled using [style.css](https://github.com/michal-h21/tex4ht-doc/blob/master/style.css). The last component of the TOC handling is in [build.mk4](https://github.com/michal-h21/tex4ht-doc/blob/master/build.mk4). The `collapsetoc` filter will clean up the TOC and show only current sections.

This is how it looks:

[image]

Comment: You got it. Thanks! Need to add a page to list the things that I use to build the site so that it can be seen that I use `make4ht`.

Comment: Wow, this is new to my knowledge, as usual classic answer....